# Network Interfaces names Cent OS 7

Tags: virtualbox, centos7

I recently wrote a script to monitor my network interfaces in Cent OS 7. 
The names were like the new names for the network interfaces - so far so good (more or less). 
After I cloned the OS (it was a virtual machine) I saw that the network names of the cloned machine (my used Hypervisor is the VirtualBox) where like the old ones (e.g. eth0, eth1 and so on). 

I understand the advantages of the new names and why they have changed in time. But why were the network interface names of the cloned OS similar to the old names?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking (english not my primary language). On a modern kernel with modern (uefi) bios network interface names are taken from bios and may be named en* (but there is a kernel boot option that reverts to old names). Otherwise you'll get the usual eth*

Comment: I am sorry for my bad english skills.
I'm going to try to explain my problem more accurately now.
I installed Cent OS7 in virtual Box and cloned the VM. 
Ater that I saw that ne network names from the original VM were like "en****". 
The cloned machine did not have these network interface names.  Those names were like "eth0", "eth1" and so on. 
My question is: Why happened this? My expectation was, that the cloned machine does have network names like "en***", too.

Comment: I suppose somehow on the new machine the kernel was not able to get interface names from bios and reverted to default eth* names. If the cloned machine has the same virtual hardware and settings, then I don't know. Usually you can change the interface names to whatever you want by modifying udev configuration.

Comment: I added some more virtual NICS to the VMs. Now the names are mixed up. Some names are like "ethX", some are like "en***" and some are like "p2p1". This is a hell of a mess... I want to understand why this happens.

Comment: Add biosdevname=0 to kernel boot flags to make the kernel not use the new naming scheme. And read here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming_Using_biosdevname.html

Comment: Thanks for the awesome info ! But unfortunately it does not explain why my VMs used names like ethX and p1p2 and em3 simultaneously.

Comment: Sorry that is too much of a guesswork.